# Angular 2.0 Meteor: How to subscribe collection correctly?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-meteor

I've introduced a publisher for a collection on the server side with the following code:

`Meteor.publish('posts', () => Posts.find());`

Now I want to subscribe to the collection on the client side. As an example I want to print the number of entries in the collection to the console, whenever the data has changed:

`ngOnInit() {
    Meteor.subscribe('posts', () => { 
        console.log(Posts.find().count());
    });
 }`

The result is somehow confusing to me:

`Observable {_isScalar: false, source: ObservableCursor, operator: CountOperator}`

It seems I've misunderstood the whole concept. What is the right way to implement this functionallity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing some common code, which I usually put in /common

model.js:

```
// Collections that exist on the server database
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");
```

The effect of this is to make 'Posts' a variable in both client and server code.

Component code:

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts', () => []);

this.helpers({
  posts: () => Posts.find(),
```

Answer (score 0):

On client side I created a `count` function:

```
myCount(p:any) {
    return p.fetch().length;
}
```

and in my `html` page I added that function:

```
{{ myCount(posts) }}
```